# Package third party dll in context of multi target framework project, .Net Framework & .Net Core

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, nuget, visual-studio-2019

I'm using next configuration within csproj :

```
  <ItemGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.StartsWith('net4'))">
    <Reference Include="amqmdnet">
      <HintPath>..\bin\amqmdnet.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Content Include="..\bin\amqmdnet.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <Pack>true</Pack>
      <PackagePath>lib\$(TargetFramework)</PackagePath>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.StartsWith('netstandard2')) or $(TargetFramework.StartsWith('netcoreapp3'))">
    <Reference Include="amqmdnetstd">
      <HintPath>..\bin\amqmdnetstd.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Content Include="..\bin\amqmdnetstd.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <Pack>true</Pack>
      <PackagePath>lib\$(TargetFramework)</PackagePath>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

each part of it working fine when the project is set with a concrete framework, for example :

```
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
```

but when the project is multi framework noting happened, dlls are not included

```
    <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp3.1;net451</TargetFrameworks>
```

I'm getting this message in multi framework scenario, this is the only context:

[image: Visual Studio hint in multi framework project]

[image: Visula Studio version, about dialog]

---

## How I proceeded

For some reason `nuget spec` doesn't fill metadata; I test it with `nuget` version 5.5.1.6542.

1. I build the project with VS, how it is.
2. Change extension of {project folder}\bin\Release\xxx.nupkg to .zip
3. Extract xxx.nuspec file from xxx.zip. It will contain also dependencies metadata.
4. Edit xxx.nuspec with  [NuGet Package Explorer](https://github.com/NuGetPackageExplorer/NuGetPackageExplorer)
5. Build `nuget xxx.nuspec`
6. [.nuspec documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec)

---

## Answer

See this [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1016281/package-third-party-dll-in-context-of-multi-target.html). [NuGet doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#advanced-extension-points-to-create-customized-package)

I will post it and here:

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>

<TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput>$(TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput);GetMyPackageFiles</TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput>
  </PropertyGroup>


  <Target Name="GetMyPackageFiles">
    <ItemGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.StartsWith('net4'))">
      <BuildOutputInPackage Include="amqmdnet.dll">
        <FinalOutputPath>..\bin\amqmdnet.dll</FinalOutputPath>
      </BuildOutputInPackage>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.StartsWith('netstandard2')) or $(TargetFramework.StartsWith('netcoreapp3'))">
      <BuildOutputInPackage Include="amqmdnetstd.dll">
        <FinalOutputPath>..\bin\amqmdnetstd.dll</FinalOutputPath>
      </BuildOutputInPackage>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Package third party dll in context of multi target framework project,
>   .Net Framework & .Net Core

I tried your sample and face the same issue in my side. When I use `TargetFrameworks` to set such dll into multi target framework projects and face the same situation.

And the `<pack>true</pack>` does not work due to your condition. But when I looked into output folder in such project, `<CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>` works. And according to the conditions, copy the two types of dll to the corresponding target framework folder.

**However**, **pack** does not work,still quite be strange.

So l report this issue to our DC Forum. See [this link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1016281/package-third-party-dll-in-context-of-multi-target.html). You can vote this issue and add any comments if I did not describe the issue in detailed. And anyone who is interested in this issue will vote for you so that it will get more attention from the staff.

**Suggestion**

**As a suggestion**, you can [use nuspec file with nuget.exe cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package) to pack your project which I have tested successfully.

**1)** download [nuget.exe](https://www.nuget.org/downloads) from this link and config its path into System Environment Variable **PATH**.

**2)** call Developer Command Prompt for VS or CMD and then `cd` your project path(which `xxx.csproj` exists)

Then call `nuget spec` and get `xxx.nuspec` file

**3)** open `xxx.nuspec` file and modify like these:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    ......
  </metadata>

<files>
<file src="bin\Debug\net451\amqmdnet.dll" target="lib\net451" />
<file src="bin\Debug\net451\PRCB.IBM.MQ.dll" target="lib\net451"/>
<file src="bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\amqmdnetstd.dll" target="lib\netcoreapp3.1" />
<file src="bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\PRCB.IBM.MQ.dll" target="lib\netcoreapp3.1" />
</files>

</package>
```

**4)** Finally, type `nuget pack xxx.nuspec` and you will get the `xxx.nupkg` file.

Comment: Thanks, I have the intention to create an issue at https://github.com/microsoft/msbuild

Comment: It seems that when the multi-project framework project is packaged, the condition content conflicts with the pack node, and when I remove the condition, everything is fine again. So far, you can try `nuget.exe` to pack the project. It can avoid your current problems.

Comment: If you have a better solution, you can share the answer with  us here. If my solution does work to achieve your requirement, you could consider accepting it  since the problem may take a while to fix so that it will create a good atmosphere. Thanks:)